# Enviar formulario sem atualizar a pagina

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho uma página de cadastro e queria que assim fosse enviado meu formulário a página não atualizasse e abrisse uma `div` oculta.

Com o *script* abaixo não deixa a minha página atualizar, mas também não envia meu formulário para o banco de dados:

```js
<script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#meufrm').submit(function(){
            var dados = jQuery(this).serialize();

            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "vendas.php",
            data: dados,
            success: function( data )
            {                   
            if (data == "")

            }
            });

            return false;
            });
            });
```

Esse outro *script* oculta minha `div` que funciona certinho:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                function mostra() {
                    if (document.getElementById('teste').style.display == 'block'){
                        document.getElementById('teste').style.display = 'none';
                    }else {document.getElementById('teste').style.display = 'block'}
                }

            </script>
```

Comment: "mas também nao envia meu formulario para o banco " - como assim? podes explicar o que falha?

Comment: tipo quando eu aperto no botao submit a pagina nao atualiza e abre a div oculta , mais os dados do formulario nao e enviado para o banco de dados entende ?

Comment: @MatheusGoes e o que diz a consola? erros? na parte da network mostra o pedido ajax a sair? o que chega no servidor?  "vendas.php" é o ficheiro certo? qual é o código desse ficheiro?

Answer (score 0):

Cria um botão para dar o `submit`.

### HTML

```
<form action="" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">        
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">

    <input type="button" id="enviaDados" name="" value="Envia">
</form>
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#enviaDados").on('click', function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'vendas.php',
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                success: function(){

                }
            })
        });
    });
```

Caso ainda dê algum problema, pode ser em seu arquivo `vendas.php`.

Comment: eu ja tenho um botao para dar o submit ,o poblema seria no meu codigo javascript pois assim que eu removo essa parte do script "  {         if (data == "")

            }" ele envia normalmente

Comment: É porque seu `if` não está abrindo a chaves. Só está fechando. `if(data == ''"){ }`. Faltou abrir.

Comment: Tentei desse jeito mais nada mudou ;/

Comment: Dá algum erro ? Veja no Inspect Element do Chrome.

Comment: Opa aparece esse erro aqui "Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.c....maskedinput.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

Comment: Não tem nada a ver com essa parte do script, então. Tem a ver com esse plugin de máscara.